# Java: How can I loop through n number of arrays in Java? The arrays are passed as one Object array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, comparable

The goal is to loop through 0 through n sets of numbers and find whichever numbers are in common to all the sets that were passed through. I know how to find the sets that are in common if I hard code the method to accept a specific number of Comparable[]. But lets say I want to store three Comparable[] into one Object[] and pass the Object[] as an argument to a method. How can I "unroll" the three Comparable[] out of the Object[] so that I can operate on them?

Here is the hard-coded method that works:

```
public static Comparable[] compare2(Comparable[] test1, Comparable[] test2,
        Comparable[] test3) {
    Comparable[] inCommon = new Comparable[25];
    int counter = 0;
    int comparisons = 0;
    for (Comparable c : test1) {
        for (Comparable d : test2) {
            comparisons++;
            if (c.compareTo(d) == 0) {
                for (Comparable e : test3) {
                    comparisons++;
                    if (d.compareTo(e) == 0) {
                        inCommon[counter] = c;
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(comparisons);
    return inCommon;
```

After it returns the Comparable[], I have written a print method that displays the numbers that are in common to all three sets. I want to be able to do that even when I pass an Object[] to my compare method instead of a specific number of Comparable[]. In my main file, I am able to create 0 through N sets of numbers and I'd like for my compare method to be able to find the in-common numbers no matter how many sets are passed to it. I tried to write a recursive function. That didn't work out too well because it gets messy really quickly when I try to use a counter to keep my place. I also tried to write a second method that compares only 2 collections at a time, but that didn't work. The goal is to have my method work like this:

```
Comparable[] test1 = {1, 2, 3};
Comparable[] test2 = {2, 3, 4};
Comparable[] test3 = {2, 3, 5};
Object[] sets = {test1, test2, test3};

public static Comparable[] compare3(Object[] sets){
    // I need to unravel the Object[] and then process however many
    // Comparable[] are inside the Object[] 
}
```

Comment: A recursive method will solve your problem.

Comment: Any tips on how the recursive method should start out? I tried to write a method that calls itself and starts at collections[counter+1] every time, but I don't know if that's the right track.

Comment: you mean you want to send array of comparable array instead of fix number of array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a structure like the following:

```
private static Comparable[] compareRecur(Object[] sets, Comparable[] inCommon, int counter){
    // base condition
    if (counter == inCommon.length)
       return comparisions;

    // I need to unravel the Object[] and then process however many
    // call the method recursively 
    // increment counter at every run
}

public static Comparable[] compare3(Object[] sets) {
   return compareRecur(sets, new Comparable[25], 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to something like this :-

//This program is not assumption, you each 1 D array is of same size.

```
  public Comparable[] recursiveCompare(Comparable[][] comparable , int index , Comparable[] commonElements){
       //this index show till from which index comparison needs to start
       if(index < comparable.length - 1){
         Comparabale[] comparable1 = comparable[index];
         Comparabale[] comparable1 = comparable[index  +1 ]; 
          for(Comparable compare1 : comparable1 ){
               for(Comparable compare2 : comparable2 ){
                     if(compare1.compareTo(compare2)){
                                     inCommon[counter] = c;
                    counter++;
                    break;[counter] = c;
                    counter++;
                    break;
 }


          }

          }


      }else{
          return commonElements[];

     }



 }

 public static Comparable[] compare2(comparable[][]){
```

//Max common element can be m * n. or if it is lesser that change accordingly
   Comparable[] inCommon = new Comparable[comparable[].length * comparable[1].lenght];

```
  System.out.println(inCommon.lenght);
```

}

You can achieve by simply iterationg through loop and comparing consecutive arrays. Using old for with index loop. I have not complied the code

Comment: I am not having java with me. So kindly compile by your self. Sorry for misspellings as i have written this on notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach. This method takes `Object[]` as input and returns common `Comparable[]` the way you wanted. To make computation simple I used [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
    Comparable[] setA = {1, 2, 3};
    Comparable[] setB = {2, 3, 4};
    Comparable[] setC = {2, 3, 5};      
    Object[] allSets = {setA, setB, setC};
    Comparable commonElements[] = compareAll(allSets);
}

public static Comparable[] compareAll(Object[] allSets){
    Comparable[] firstSet = (Comparable[]) allSets[0];
    List<Comparable> commonElements = new ArrayList<Comparable>(Arrays.asList(firstSet));
    for(Object setAsObject : allSets){
        Comparable[] set = (Comparable[]) setAsObject;
        List<Comparable> thisSet = new ArrayList<Comparable>(Arrays.asList(set));
        commonElements.retainAll(thisSet);
    }
    return commonElements.toArray(new Comparable[]{});
}
```